# Configuring vmware networking to access static IP

Tags: networking, vmware

I have a dedicated virtual debian server running with my website, and now have a copy of that so that I can try some configurations by running it virtually on my own PC. It runs fine, but I'm unable to access the machine through http.

The problem is that my machine has a fixed ip, something like 194.247.x.x . My home network however has computers in the range of 192.168.1.x

Is it possible to not change anything in my virtual machine and still configure vmware networking so that I'm able to access the websites it's running?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this happening for you is to use NAT (Network Address Translation) between your home network and your VM.

To do this, you could use a free software based router - something like Vyatta ([www.vyatta.org](http://www.vyatta.org)) - and create a VM with two NICs - one with an IP on your home network, and the other with an IP on the same network as your VM. You then configure NAT to translate your home IP to your web server IP and then you're done.

There's nothing 'de-facto' VMware that will allow you to do this (other than using vShield - which will do NAT'ing anyway)...

Comment: Or - you could set a 194.247.x.x address on your PC in the same subnet. If your server IP is 194.247.1.10, you can set an additional virtual adapter on your PC to use 194.247.1.11, then you should be able to hit your server directly. No need for software based NAT'ing.